# php namespace on class only

Tags: php, namespaces

For example,I want to Notifyer will be in Myapp namespace and Order in global name space.
However,in following code.Both Order and Notifyer are in Myapp namesapce.

```
<?php
namespace Myapp;
class Notifyer
{
    public function sendInfo(Order $order){...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a backslash in front of a class will refer to the global namespace. Try:

```
public function sendInfo(\Order $order){...}
```